# The JDK 18.0.1 isn't compatible with Gradle 4.4.1

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, java-home

I used Mac Machine and IntelliJ Idea. I found this Compatibility Matrix of `Gradel` and `Java`.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

I try to import this project https://github.com/udacity/ud282
from Github and when I try to run build.Gradle it shows me error Message:

```
JDK 18.0.1 isn't compatible with Gradle 4.4.1. Please fix JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

when I ask the `shell` to show me `JAVA_HOME` using `echo $JAVA_HOME` command it shows the path

```
/Users/lama/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home
```

And another error Message:

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 16.0.2. It's recommended to use Gradle 7.0 or newer.

Possible solution:
 - Use Java 1.8 as Gradle JVM: Open Gradle settings 
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project
```

When I ask the `shell` about the `Gradle` version `gradle -v` it shows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          18.0.1.1 (Oracle Corporation 18.0.1.1+2-6)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.6 x86_64
```

Comment: That project uses a very old version of Gradle which is not compatible with Java 18. I can see in the file [`gradle-wrapper.properties`](https://github.com/udacity/ud282/blob/master/Project%201%20-%20TicTacToe/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) in the project that it downloads Gradle 4.4.1.

Comment: The `gradle -v` output is your locally installed gradle. Most projects use a gradle wrapepr to use their own defined gradle version. The project you link to explicitly references Gradle 4.4.1. So no matter what else you have installed locally, if you run `./gradlew` (or your IDE does the equivalent) then that version will be used (and downloaded, if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatibility matrix you mentioned (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) specifically says no version of Gradle (currently at version 7.4.2) is compatible with Java 18 yet.

Your best bet is to try installing/switching to an older version of Java (like 8 perhaps) and running the `./gradlew` wrapper as @Joachim Sauer suggested. That should automatically download and install Gradle 4.4.1.

Comment: 1. Set the compatible JDK version in the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM**